# Using while loop inside a verilog always block

Tags: verilog

I am kind of new to verilog and I was writing this code but I was wondering how it would synthesize:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  //do some stuff
  while(test == 0) begin
     count <= count + 1;
  end
end
```

my question is will the count increase continuously until test != 0 at one posedge trigger OR will it increment once and then increment again on the next posedge if the test condition is satisfied?

Comment: Why are you using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will not synthesizable as the number of loops cannot be determined at compile time. In order for a loop to be synthesizable, the synthesis tool needs to be able to unroll the loop. However, as the loop you have provided might run once, a bunch of times or not at all, the synthesis tool cannot unroll the loop to generate the correct hardware and thus will not be able to synthesis the loop.

In order to implement the "loop" such that `test` is checked at each clock edge, you need only have that be the condition of incrementing the counter (however, note that counter will never increment more than once per clock which is what your loop will do anyway, but I assume you might want counter to increment maybe more than one per clock, which would require more logic):

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (test == 0) begin
    counter <= counter + 1;
  end
end
```

However, in simulation, this code will lock up if `test` is 0 as despite everyone telling you so, Verilog simulation isnt really concurrent. So, the process will hang on the non-blocking assignment of `counter` and if `test` is set to 1 somewhere else, that code will never run (or has run, in which case `test` should be 1 already :P ). So to answer your second question, it will do neither, but instead either run forever stuck in that loop or never run the loop at all.

Comment: Thank you! So a while loop is generally not synthesizable ?

Comment: Generally no; but they are a useful construct in simulations for testbenches and verification code. I think they might also be useful in functions that might be synthesizable but Im not really sure as I havent used many while loops in synthesizable code. Typically when you are using a while loop, you want something to happen over multiple clock cycles, so no while loop actually appears in the synthesizable code